# Copy using the Windows copy dialog

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm currently using `shutil.copy2()` to copy a large number of image files and folders (anywhere between 0.5 and 5 gigs).  `Shutil` works fine, but it's so slow.  I'm wondering if there is a way to pass this info over to Windows to make the copy and give me its standard transfer dialog box.  You know, this guy...

[image: http://www.top-windows-tutorials.com/images/file-copy.jpg]

Many times, my script will take about twice the time the standard windows copy takes, and it makes me nervous that my python interpreter hangs while running the copy.  I run the copy process multiple times and I'm looking to cut the time down.

Comment: Have you actually timed file transfers of the same file using both Python and Windows Explorer? I have a very hard time believing that Python is actually slower.

Comment: Yes, I did a side by side test.  It's across a network, so perhaps network speeds were interfering, but how do I find my transfer speeds with shutil?

Comment: You could use `time.clock()` in Python to get the transfer time, but you'd have to use a stopwatch to time Explorer. My assumption would be that both Python and Explorer make the same library call to perform the copy, but Explorer feels faster because of the progress bar and maybe because of some incorrect time estimates that it gives you.  If you ran both at the same time and saw huge differences, that is quite interesting!

Comment: I've found posts online about shutil being slower as well... Perhaps I will do a more scientific test at some point.  Either way, I'd still like to dump the copy to Windows so I don't have to wait for the copy to finish before continuing the script.  Perhaps this is a multi-thread question?

Comment: After testing locally and over our network on a different day, I've found shutil to be just as fast.  I'm guessing it was a network traffic issue.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is a fancy copy dialog, [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API function provides that.
pywin32 package has a python binding for it, ctypes is also an option (google "SHFileOperation ctypes" for examples).

Here is my (very lightly tested) example using pywin32:

```
import os.path
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon


def win32_shellcopy(src, dest):
    """
    Copy files and directories using Windows shell.

    :param src: Path or a list of paths to copy. Filename portion of a path
                (but not directory portion) can contain wildcards ``*`` and
                ``?``.
    :param dst: destination directory.
    :returns: ``True`` if the operation completed successfully,
              ``False`` if it was aborted by user (completed partially).
    :raises: ``WindowsError`` if anything went wrong. Typically, when source
             file was not found.

    .. seealso:
        `SHFileperation on MSDN <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx>`
    """
    if isinstance(src, basestring):  # in Py3 replace basestring with str
        src = os.path.abspath(src)
    else:  # iterable
        src = '\0'.join(os.path.abspath(path) for path in src)

    result, aborted = shell.SHFileOperation((
        0,
        shellcon.FO_COPY,
        src,
        os.path.abspath(dest),
        shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR,  # flags
        None,
        None))

    if not aborted and result != 0:
        # Note: raising a WindowsError with correct error code is quite
        # difficult due to SHFileOperation historical idiosyncrasies.
        # Therefore we simply pass a message.
        raise WindowsError('SHFileOperation failed: 0x%08x' % result)

    return not aborted
```

You can also perform the same copy operation in "silent mode" (no dialog, no confirmationsm, no error popups) if you set the flags above to `shellcon.FOF_SILENT | shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | shellcon.FOF_NOERRORUI | shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR.` See [SHFILEOPSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: I have asked here on the return values of the `shell.SHFileOperation` for a _delete_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053189/python-win32com-shell-shfileoperation-any-way-to-get-the-files-that-were-actua. Can't seem to find any docs

Comment: And here I am again wondering if `src = os.path.abspath(src)` should be `src = os.path.abspath(src) + '\0'` (same with the join below)

Comment: OSError: SHFileOperation failed: 0x000000b7

Answer (score 2):

Update: See

- https://github.com/tjguk/winshell/
- https://github.com/frmdstryr/pywinutils

Would be nice to have it wrapped in a library... With the help of the answers above, I was able to get it working on windows 7 as follows.

```
import pythoncom
from win32com.shell import shell,shellcon

def win_copy_files(src_files,dst_folder):           
        # @see IFileOperation
        pfo = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_FileOperation,None,pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL,shell.IID_IFileOperation)

        # Respond with Yes to All for any dialog
        # @see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775799(v=vs.85).aspx
        pfo.SetOperationFlags(shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION)

        # Set the destionation folder
        dst = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(dst_folder,None,shell.IID_IShellItem)

        for f in src_files:
                src = shell.SHCreateItemFromParsingName(f,None,shell.IID_IShellItem)
                pfo.CopyItem(src,dst) # Schedule an operation to be performed


        # @see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775780(v=vs.85).aspx
        success = pfo.PerformOperations()

        # @see sdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775769(v=vs.85).aspx
        aborted = pfo.GetAnyOperationsAborted()
        return success and not aborted


files_to_copy = [r'C:\Users\jrm\Documents\test1.txt',r'C:\Users\jrm\Documents\test2.txt']
dest_folder = r'C:\Users\jrm\Documents\dst'
win_copy_files(files_to_copy,dest_folder)
```

The references here were also very helpful: 
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html

Comment: Sorry to reply so late, but this looks very promising.  I'm getting an error running this saying that the shell module doesn't have a CLSID_FileOperation attribute.

Comment: CLSID_FileOperation was not in the pip version of pywin32. Do you have pywin32 version 218.4+? See https://github.com/frmdstryr/pywinutils

Comment: CLSID_FileOperation is in pywin 220

Comment: Actually it was added in 219: http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/raw-file/tip/CHANGES.txt. Apparently however some functionality is absent - for instance I can't get any constant for the IFileSystemBindData interface.

Answer (score 1):

See [IFileCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771.aspx). IFileOperation *may* be available through ctypes and shell32.dll, I am not sure.

Comment: ctypes.windll.shell32.SHFileOperation exists, but ctypes.windll.shell32.IFileOperation does not (Windows 10, Python 3.8)

Comment: @Jay it's a COM interface, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

*bump* Windows 10!

With all your help and [Virgil Dupras' **send2trash**](https://github.com/hsoft/send2trash/blob/master/send2trash/plat_win.py):
I just cooked a **vanilla** Python version only using `ctypes`:

```
import os
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes


class _SHFILEOPSTRUCTW(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("hwnd", wintypes.HWND),
                ("wFunc", wintypes.UINT),
                ("pFrom", wintypes.LPCWSTR),
                ("pTo", wintypes.LPCWSTR),
                ("fFlags", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("fAnyOperationsAborted", wintypes.BOOL),
                ("hNameMappings", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("lpszProgressTitle", wintypes.LPCWSTR)]


def win_shell_copy(src, dst):
    """
    :param str src: Source path to copy from. Must exist!
    :param str dst: Destination path to copy to. Will be created on demand.
    :return: Success of the operation. False means is was aborted!
    :rtype: bool
    """
    if not os.path.exist(src):
        print('No such source "%s"' % src)
        return False

    src_buffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(src, len(src) + 2)
    dst_buffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(dst, len(dst) + 2)

    fileop = _SHFILEOPSTRUCTW()
    fileop.hwnd = 0
    fileop.wFunc = 2  # FO_COPY
    fileop.pFrom = wintypes.LPCWSTR(ctypes.addressof(src_buffer))
    fileop.pTo = wintypes.LPCWSTR(ctypes.addressof(dst_buffer))
    fileop.fFlags = 512  # FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR
    fileop.fAnyOperationsAborted = 0
    fileop.hNameMappings = 0
    fileop.lpszProgressTitle = None

    result = ctypes.windll.shell32.SHFileOperationW(ctypes.byref(fileop))
    return not result
```

✔ Tested on Python 3.7 and 2.7 also with long src and dst paths.

Comment: Most useful answer, however I read that IFileOperation has replaced SHFileOperationW since Vista. Have you found a way to use it from ctypes?

Comment: thanks! But no. I have no clue about `IFileOperation` yet. I can imagine that `ctypes.windll` would need to be updated for this. I mean "shell32" doesn't sound like > year 2000 :|

Comment: Maybe in Python 3.9 then :)