# Copy with SHFileOperation for files in non-drive-letter like Computer\Phone\card\DCIM\test.jpg

Tags: python, windows, shell, winapi, pywin32

Context: I know that using [`SHFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationw) for copying with Windows Shell has been replaced by `IFileOperation` (*"Copies, moves, renames, or deletes a file system object. This function has been replaced in Windows Vista by [`IFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation)"*).
But `IFileOperation` / `CopyItem` is not supported for all types of devices on Windows 7 (which I need to support), see [Copy file with Windows using Shell API ("No such interface supported")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77277997/copy-file-with-windows-using-shell-api-no-such-interface-supported), that's why I want to make `SHFileOperation` work for my application, like in [Copy using the Windows copy dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867615/copy-using-the-windows-copy-dialog).

**Question: is there a way to make `SHFileOperation` work in Windows 7 with paths like `Computer\Phone\card\DCIM\test.jpg` i.e. not in a volume / no drive letter?**

Example:

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
dest = r"E:\Temp"
for src in [r"E:\Temp2\test.txt", r"Computer\Phone\card\DCIM\test.jpg"]:
    result, aborted = shell.SHFileOperation((0, shellcon.FO_COPY, src, dest, shellcon.FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR, None, None))
    print(result, aborted)
```

Result:

```
E:\Temp2\test.txt                 0   False      # success
Computer\Phone\card\DCIM\test.jpg 124 False      # not working
```

Comment: I think this should be work fine: https://pastebin.com/qrJNg8uV

Comment: @Andrew Why pastebin, and not posting an answer? Also this doesn't work, try doing this on Win7: `copy "Computer\Phone\card\DCIM\test.jpg"  e:\temp`  (modify with your own phone name and paths). `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: SHFileOperation is a simple wrapper over IFileOperation. The question is It's not a drive vs other path question, it's whether the code that handles the hieararchy in question (a namespace extension that implements IShellFolder, even standard drive support is one) supports this or not. Not all supports full parsing names/paths from the root. And not all support copying, ie: getting content - whatever that means for the storage in question - using a stream for example).

Comment: @Basj pastebin cause I don't have win7 to test this) U can try dst_path.absolute() to fix relative path in src directory.

Comment: @Basj I dont see how it would be possible if Win7 does not support the required interface. A replacement may be the [WPD API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/wpd-application-programming-interface) with [IProgressDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nn-shlobj_core-iprogressdialog) if you want to show the progress. [Here a sample for file transfer](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/multimedia/wpd/wpdapisample/cpp/ContentTransfer.cpp#L158).

Comment: @Stuntman11 I'm not sure if Win7 has the required interface or not, maybe I'm just using it in a wrong way.

Comment: @Stuntman11 I looked at your example for file transfer, it seems quite low level (read the file content manually, rewriting it), it will be tedious if I want to persist eveything (date creation time and other metadata). Or do you see an easier solution?

Comment: @Basj Well I agree that it is tedious and an easier solution is preferred. To copy all the metadata you may use `IShellItem2::GetPropertyStore` for the host system and `IPortableDeviceResources::GetResourceAttributes` with `IPortableDeviceValues::CopyValuesToPropertyStore` on the portable device.